# Oracle : merge two rows values into one row with new column names

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

The version I'm using is Oracle database 12c.

```
select id,currency_code,currency_classification_code,amount from table;
```

DATA :

```
id   currency_code    currency_classification_code    Amount
1    USD              Reporting                       111111
1    AUD              BASE                            222222
```

Expected result :

```
id   Amt_in_base_curncy  base_curncy_code  Amt_in_rptng_curncy rptng_curncy_code
1    222222              AUD               111111              USD
```

I want the data in the above format , by creating four new columns.

please let me know if you need more details.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is conditional aggregation:

```
select id, 
max(case when currency_classification_code = 'BASE' then Amount end) as Amt_in_base_curncy,
max(case when currency_classification_code = 'BASE' then currency_code end) as base_curncy_code,
max(case when currency_classification_code = 'Reporting' then Amount end) as Amt_in_rptng_curncy,
max(case when currency_classification_code = 'Reporting' then currency_code end) as rptng_curncy_code
from t
group by id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `join`, for instance:

```
select tb.id, tb.amount, tb.currency_code, tr.amount, tr.currency_code
from t tr join
     t tb
     on tr.id = tb.id and tr.currency_classification_code = 'Reporting' and
        tb.currency_classification_code = 'BASE';
```

Comment: I tried it but it is returning duplicate rows. If in the source table if we have 10 rows and if we run the above query we are getting more than 50 rows like thta, its returning duplicate rows.

Answer (score 1):

Let's go another route:

If you can't be certain that in all cases you'll have BOTH a 'BASE' and a 'Reporting' row for each ID you'll need to use a FULL JOIN to put the data together:

```
WITH cteBase AS (SELECT *
                   FROM YOUR_TABLE
                   WHERE CURRENCY_CLASSIFICATION_CODE = 'BASE'),
     cteReporting AS (SELECT *
                        FROM YOUR_TABLE
                        WHERE CURRENCY_CLASSIFICATION_CODE = 'Reporting')
SELECT COALESCE(b.ID, r.ID) AS ID,
       b.AMOUNT AS Amt_in_base_curncy,
       b.CURRENCY_CODE AS base_curncy_code,
       r.AMOUNT AS Amt_in_rptng_curncy,
       r.CURRENCY_CODE AS rptng_curncy_code
  FROM cteBase b
  FULL OUTER JOIN cteReporting r
    ON r.ID = b.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Exactly for this kind of problems `Oracle` has the `PIVOT`-queries:

```
select *
  from (select id,currency_code,currency_classification_code,amount from table)
  pivot (sum(amount) as amt_in
        ,max(currency_code) as code 
     for (currency_classification_code) in ('BASE' as base_curncy, 'Reporting' as rptng_curncy))
```